# How can I share setup and teardown methods across packages when testing Go?

Tags: testing, go

Let's say I have two packages `foo` and `bar`. Each package has file and a test file:

```
foo
---widget.go
---widget_test.go
bar
---wingding.go
---wingding_test.go
```

Now for both tests (widget_test.go and wingding_test.go) I want to share some setup code. I know I can put this code inside each package inside main_test.go. But I obviously don't want to copy/paste code in two places. So where can I put this code so that it's shared across packages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put it in another package `baz` that both `foo` and `bar` import in their tests.  We use this for database setup and teardown code in our tests.